What causes genetic drift?
I read that it occurs by chance, however since it's an important effect, is it really so random? are there any factors that enhance it or hinder it? Thank you
Also how do studbooks in zoos prevent genetic drift?

Its worth reading up on Ernst Myer's work on population genetics and his theory of speciation

homework questions are expected to show effort to answer the question on your own.

@john this is not a homework question, i'm not in school

@upquark homework questions is shorthand for a question at the level of basic homework. either way you are expected to show some effort to research the topic on your own first.

There are a lot of non-random processes in evolution.
"Genetic drift" is just the name/label applied to the remaining random part. If it were non-random, it wouldn't be genetic drift, it would be something else.
Randomness is more important in a small sample, which is why there's a bigger effect of genetic drift when a population shrinks (bottleneck) or a new population is established (founder effect).
Zoos and other artificial breeding programs act to mitigate bottlenecks and founder effects by keeping track of lineages and preserving genetic diversity by breeding more distant lineages. That doesn't do anything to eliminate genetic drift besides increasing the population, it acts against the non-random way that the surviving population is sampled (for example, if only individuals in a small geographical area survive in the wild).

thank you! why is genetic diversity preserved by breeding more distant lineages?

@upquark Because they are more genetically diverse by virtue of being more distantly related. At the other extreme would be inbreeding within just one family.
